# How to NFSv4 share a ZFS file system on FreeBSD?

Tags: linux, freebsd, nfs, zfs

Using FreeBSD 9, and created a ZFS file system like so

```
zfs create tank/project1
zfs set sharenfs=on tank/project1
```

There are many howto's on setting up NFSv3 on FreeBSD on the net, but I can't find any one NFSv4 and when the NFS share is done with ZFS.

E.g. [this](http://linux-bsd-sharing.blogspot.dk/2008/09/howto-setup-nfs-server-on-freebsd.html) howto say I have to restart the (NFSv3) by `nfsd -u -t -n 4`, but I don't even have `nfsd`.

When I do

```
# echo /usr/ports/*/*nfs*
/usr/ports/net-mgmt/nfsen /usr/ports/net/nfsshell /usr/ports/net/pcnfsd /usr/ports/net/unfs3 /usr/ports/sysutils/fusefs-chironfs /usr/ports/sysutils/fusefs-funionfs /usr/ports/sysutils/fusefs-unionfs
#
```

I don't see any NFSv4 servers, which I could install with `pkg_add`.

**Question**

How do I install and setup NFSv4, so I can mount the share from e.g. a Linux host?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NFSv4 is built in on FreeBSD (Experimental support in 8.x, production quality in 9.x and later).
The nfsd should be located in `/etc/rc.d/nfsd`

You should first enable it within rc.conf file or running `/etc/rc.d/nfsd onestart`

1. Enable nfs

   ```
   echo nfs_server_enable="YES" >> /etc/rc.conf
   ```

   For NFSv4 you will also need the following:

   `echo nfsv4_server_enable="YES" >> /etc/rc.conf`  (To enable NFSv4)
   `echo nfsuserd_enable="YES" >> /etc/rc.conf`      (The NFS user/group info needed for v4)
2. Create directories and export them

   ```
   # mkdir -p /mnt/{dir1,dir2}
   # vi /etc/exports
   ```

   (add the following lines to the `/etc/exports` file)

   ```
   /mnt/dir1  -alldirs  192.168.1.x/24
   /mnt/dir2  -alldirs  192.168.1.x/24
   ```
3. restart nfsd either using `/etc/rc.d/nfsd restart`  or  `service nfsd restart`

See [The section of the FreeBSD handbook dealing with NFS](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/network-nfs.html) for more information.

Comment: This works perfectly fine with BSD FFS / UFS. It doesn't answer the question for ZFS though, unless I'm very mistaken.